# VBA macro using word SaveAs FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF creates .docx

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word, vba

```
wordTemplate = "c:\someTemplate.docx"
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.documents.Add Template:=wordTemplate, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

'''here I iterate and do stuffs, and then:'''


With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs Filename:=("somePath" & "aName"), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    .Close
End With
With objWord
    .Quit
End With
```

this is resulting in a .docx file. ¿shouldn't wdFormatPDF give me a PDF?

EDIT:
I modified the .SaveAs line to:

```
.SaveAs Filename:=(Hoja1.Range("N6").Text & Hoja1.Range("A1") & ".pdf"), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

and

```
.SaveAs2 Filename:=(Hoja1.Range("N6").Text & Hoja1.Range("A1") & ".pdf"), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

but both generate a .pdf file that cannot be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my problem was related to the syntax:

this didn't work:

```
.SaveAs Filename:=(Hoja1.Range("N6").Text & Hoja1.Range("A1") & ".pdf"), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

while this did:

```
.SaveAs (Hoja1.Range("N6").Text & Hoja1.Range("A1") & ".pdf"), 17
```

The problem, then, was that after changing that, the

```
.Close
```

in the next line asked me to save changes to original document (something that  worked well before). It forced me to explicitly discard the changes like this:

```
.Close _
        SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Final solution is:

```
With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs (Hoja1.Range("N6").Text & Hoja1.Range("A1") & ".pdf"), 17
    .Close _
        SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

What you get depends on what you're passing as "aName". If it includes a .docx extension , for example, your PDF will have an invalid .docx extension.

It makes no difference whether you're using SaveAs or SaveAs2 for this.

Comment: sorry, appending .pdf to the end of file name generates a broken .pdf that cannot be visualized.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the `SaveAs2` method like this (tested ans it's working):

```
wordTemplate = "c:\someTemplate.docx"
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.documents.Add Template:=wordTemplate, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

'''here I iterate and do stuffs, and then:'''


With objWord.ActiveDocument

    .SaveAs2 "C:\test\MyDoc.pdf", 17

    '.SaveAs Filename:=("c:\test\" & "test"), FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
    .Close
End With
With objWord
    .Quit
End With
```

Comment: sorry, appending .pdf to the end of file name generates a broken .pdf that cannot be visualized.